# Lower Sum Inequality??

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded function on $[a,b]$ and $h=f+g$.

How can I link
$$L_P(f) + L_P(g) \leq L_P(h)$$
this relationship to prove that
$$ \underline{\int^b_a}(f) + \underline{\int^b_a}(g) \leq \underline{\int^b_a}(h)$$

If there's any better way to prove the statement right above, tell me.
The integrals above represents lower integrals, it doesn't has to be Riemann integral.

Answer (score 2):

That's the standard proof.

By definition of supremum, if $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist partitions $P', P''$ of $[a,b]$ such that $$L_{P'}(f) > \underline {\int_a^b} (f)-\varepsilon$$ and $$L_{P''}(g) > \underline {\int_a^b} (g)-\varepsilon$$ Considering a common refinement $P$ of $P'$ and $P''$ and using the relationship in your post, you get $$\underline {\int_a^b} (f) + \underline {\int_a^b} (g) < \underline {\int_a^b} (h) + 2\varepsilon$$ So you are done because of the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$.